# Why is calling close() after fopen() not closing?

Tags: c++, c, file, io

I ran across the following code in one of our in-house dlls and I am trying to understand the behavior it was showing:

```
long GetFD(long* fd, const char* fileName, const char* mode)
{
    string fileMode;

    if (strlen(mode) == 0 || tolower(mode[0]) == 'w' || tolower(mode[0]) == 'o')
        fileMode = string("w");
    else if (tolower(mode[0]) == 'a')
        fileMode = string("a");
    else if (tolower(mode[0]) == 'r')
        fileMode = string("r");
    else
        return -1;

    FILE* ofp;
    ofp = fopen(fileName, fileMode.c_str());
    if (! ofp)
        return -1;

    *fd = (long)_fileno(ofp);
    if (*fd < 0)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

long CloseFD(long fd)
{
    close((int)fd);
    return 0;
}
```

After repeated calling of GetFD with the appropriate CloseFD, the whole dll would no longer be able to do any file IO.  I wrote a tester program and found that I could GetFD 509 times, but the 510th time would error.

Using Process Explorer, the number of Handles did not increase.

So it seems that the dll is reaching the limit for the number of open files; setting `_setmaxstdio(2048)` does increase the amount of times we can call GetFD. Obviously, the close() is working quite right.

After a bit of searching, I replaced the `fopen()` call with:

```
long GetFD(long* fd, const char* fileName, const char* mode)
{
    *fd = (long)open(fileName, 2);
    if (*fd < 0)
      return -1; 

    return 0;
}
```

Now, repeatedly calling GetFD/CloseFD works.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you open a file with `fopen`, you have to close it with `fclose`, symmetrically.

The C++ runtime must be given a chance to clean up/deallocate its inner file-related structures.

Comment: Specifically, you're leaving a bunch of FILE* structures hanging around, and some OSes have a fixed size table for that, usually 512, which includes the stdin, stdout and stderr FILE*s.

Comment: ... and this explains the limit of 509: it's just 512 - stdin - stdout - stderr.

Comment: `stdio` runtime, not just C++ (that is, common to both C and C++).

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `fclose` with files opened via `fopen`, or `close` with files opened via `open`.

Answer (score 5):

The standard library you are using has a static array of `FILE` structures. Because you are not calling `fclose()`, the standard library doesn't know that the underlying files have been closed, so it doesn't know it can reuse the corresponding `FILE` structures. You get an error after it has run out of entries in the `FILE` array.

Answer (score 3):

`fopen` opens it's own file descriptor, so you'd need to do an `fclose(ofp)` in your original function to prevent running out of file descriptors. Usually, one either uses the lower level file descriptor functions `open, close` OR the buffered `fopen, fclose` functions.

Answer (score 2):

you are open the file fopen() function so u have to close the file useing fclose(), if you are using open() function and try to call fclose() function it will not work